# Include_in_parent using Nest elastic search library

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Is the IncludeInParent elastic property available in NEST C# like they have it for IncludeInAll.

If yes then how we add the IncludeInParent property to the objects.
I don't want to use fluent mapping as my index creating class is dynamic for an e.g:

```
 public ESClient CreateIndex<T>() where T : class
        {
            if (!Client.IndexExists(f => f.Index(ESIndexName)).Exists)
            {
                Client.CreateIndex(ESIndexName, c => c
                    .NumberOfReplicas(1)
                    .NumberOfShards(4)
                    .Settings(s => s
                        .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
                        .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
                    )
                    .AddMapping<T>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
               );

            }
            return this;
        }
```

Is there a way I can specify IncludeInParent like IncludeInAll as below:

```
[ElasticProperty(IncludeInAll = true)]
public List<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
```

If not I think its nice to add IncludeInParent elastic property in NEST library.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask can only be done using the fluent api.

The reply in this post [Include_In_Parent option for ElasticSearch and NEST library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502678/include-in-parent-option-for-elasticsearch-and-nest-library) may help you.

Comment: I actually added IncludeInParent Elastic property to Nest project and it work like charm.